# Joomla - как вывести компонент внутри модуля?

Tags: php, joomla

Я хочу открыть компонент в модуле, для размещения его под контентной частью на нескольких страницах сайта. Можно ли как-то организовать код модуля так, чтобы всю логику и шаблон он брал из компонента?
Компонент и модуль пишу сам.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел на одном из популярных сайтов с полезными расширениями [Component Anywhere](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/componentsanywhere)